# Splitting list based on conditional atoms in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a list

```
X = [-n,-b,-s,hello,world]
```

The output i require

```
Z1 = [-n,-b,-s]
Z2 = [hello,world]
```

If the string begins with - it should be part of Z1 list, else part of Z2 list.

Could someone provide me with some basic intuition to implement this?.

Comment: What should happen with `[-n,word,-b]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with library(apply) and library(yall) it's immediate:

```
?- partition([E]>>(E = - _), [-n,-b,-s,hello,world], N, P).
N = [-n, -b, -s],
P = [hello, world].
```

to implement in old,plain Prolog, visit the list and 'cons' the element in the desired list:

```
divide_dashed([], [], []).
divide_dashed([-E|R], [-E|Ds], Ps) :- !, divide_dashed(R, Ds, Ps).
divide_dashed([E|R], Ds, [E|Ps]) :- divide_dashed(R, Ds, Ps).
```

Comment: Hello Capelli what if the string comes in this way: '-n', it wont be recognized, is there a way to change= '-n' to -n ?

Comment: @SaulGarcia: no, you must handle the pattern: for instance, try `?- A='-n', sub_atom(A,0,1,_,-).`

Comment: @CapelliC can we use maplist instead of divide_dashed?.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan: maplist handles lists of **same** length, so is useless here. partition/4 it's the library predicate to use in this case. divide_dashed it's just a descriptive name